# HTML and Javascript: Form won't submit.

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a very basic assignment to finish and it it is to help us learn some very basic javascript.  We have to make a form and when you click a button it preforms a javascript function.  I can not figure out why it won't complete the function.  Can someone troubleshoot my code?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Order Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <label>First Name:<input type="text" id="fname" size="30" /><br><br>
   <label>Last Name:<input type="text" id="lname" size="30" /><br><br>
   <label>Number of Widgets:<input type="text" id="num" size="4" /><br><br>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>
  </form>



 <script>
 function myFunction() {
  var fname;
  var lname;
  var num;
  lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  alert("Thanks," + " " + fname + " " + lname + "for ordering" + num + " " + Widgets)

 }
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Widgets is not in quotes.

Comment: What does happen when you click the button?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put quote around Widget like so:

```
alert("Thanks," + " " + fname + " " + lname + "for ordering" + num + " " + "Widgets");
```

Also you may want to put ';' at the end too.

Quick tip for you, you can catch this error easily by open a Dev-Console

In Google Chrome Press [Ctrl+Shift+J] you will see the error show up.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Trial again with this code!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Order Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {

        var fname;
        var lname;
        var num;
        lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        num = document.getElementById("num").value;

        alert("Thanks, " +  fname + " " + lname + "for ordering" + num + " " + "Widgets")

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" name="from">
            <label>First Name:<input type="text" id="fname" size="30" /><br><br>
            <label>Last Name:<input type="text" id="lname" size="30" /><br><br>
            <label>Number of Widgets:<input type="text" id="num" size="4" /><br><br>
              <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Trial" />

        </form>





    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Order Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <label>First Name:</label><input type="text" id="fname" size="30" /><br><br>
   <label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="lname" size="30" /><br><br>
   <label>Number of Widgets:</label><input type="text" id="num" size="4" /><br><br>
   <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Send" />
  </form>



 <script>
 function myFunction() {
  var fname;
  var lname;
  var num;
  lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  alert("Thanks," + " " + fname + " " + lname + "for ordering" + num + " Widgets");
  document.document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
 }
 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined Widgets as variable but it is suppose to be a string.

```
function myFunction() {
        var fname;
        var lname;
        var num;
        lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        num = document.getElementById("num").value;
        alert("Thanks, "+fname + " " + lname + " for ordering " + num + " Widgets ")

}
```

Also you didnt mentioned the `button` type, so have added it.

```
<form>
    <label>First Name:<input type="text" id="fname" size="30" /><br><br>
    <label>Last Name:<input type="text" id="lname" size="30" /><br><br>
    <label>Number of Widgets:<input type="text" id="num" size="4" /><br><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" type ="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Please check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qam61ajy/) for demo.
Hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() {
        var fname;
        var lname;
        var num;
        lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        num = document.getElementById("num").value;

        alert("Thanks, " +  fname + " " + lname + "for ordering" + num + " " + "Widgets")
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
 <label>First Name:<input type="text" id="fname" size="30" />
    <br/><br/>
 <label>Last Name:<input type="text" id="lname" size="30" />
    <br/><br/>
 <label>Number of Widgets:<input type="text" id="num" size="4" />
    <br/><br/>
 <button id="btn">Send</button>
</form>
```